# How to have an object and its subclasses as a parameter of an object

Tags: java, generics

i have a basic question but i don't know how to solve it. pls help me!

if i have a class `Zoo`

```
public class Zoo{
    private Animal animal;
    private Long age;
}
```

and  `Animal` para is this:

```
public class Animal{
    private String name;
}
```

but now i have a new class is: `Dog` class, extends animal

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private String dogClass;
}
```

I want to make the `animal` property in `Zoo` also accept `Dog` class parameters, what should I do?

Is there an elegant way to write it like `List<? extends Animal>` ?

Comment: "what should I do?" do don't need to do anything. You can assign an instance of `Dog` to a reference of type `Animal`, because `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`.

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry, i do make a mistake, is should be  `extends Animal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change anything: as `Dog` extends `Animal`, it can be assign to field `Zoo.animal`. You can however add a method in `Zoo` to get `animal` as an instance of a specific class:

```
public <T extends Animal> T getAnimal(Class<T> animalClass) {
    return animalClass.cast(animal);
}
```

Or, if you don't want it to throw an exception if the `animal` is not of the specified class:

```
public <T extends Animal> T getAnimal(Class<T> animalClass) {
    if (!animalClass.isInstance(animal)) {
        return null;
    }
    return animalClass.cast(animal);
}
```

UPDATE:

But perhaps what you want is a typed `Zoo`:

```
public class Zoo<T extends Animal> {
    private T animal;
    private Long age;

    public T getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public setAnimal(T animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! after read your answer, i try to add `if (animal.getClass().equals(Dog.class)){return (Dog) animal)` in `Zoo` class `getAnimal()` function, but it can't return a `Dog` object, I need to manually convert it.

Comment: @Guvera why would you do that? the `Zoo` class doesn't need to depend on subclasses of `Animal`.

Comment: @Guvera if you want a `Dog`, just do `Dog dog = zoo.getAnimal(Dog.class);`

Comment: yes! thank you! prefect!

Comment: Yes! Totally solved my problem! Thank you! @Maurice Perry

Comment: @Guvera perhaps I misunderstood your question. Perhaps what you want is a typed `Zoo` as in my update?

Comment: All I want is the previous `getAnimal` method, this solution is great to get the object I want directly

Comment: @Guvera BTW, `Zoo` is not a very good name for this class because we expect a zoo to have many animals, not just one.

Comment: Yes, I should have thought about the semantics of the class name, all in all, helped me a lot！   @Maurice Perry

Answer (score -2):

If I'm not mistaken, to do what you're asking, all you have to do is insert constructors in the parent and child classes and associate their values in this way:

```
public class Animal{
    private String name;
    public Animal(String name){
    this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    private String dogClass;
    public Dog(){
    super(dogClass);
    }
}
```

Also, if you already plan to never instantiate the Animal class directly, as it is a generic object, you could make it abstract.

Comment: how is dogClass supposed to be name? do you understand that  Dog inherits name from Animal? Do you also understand that in your code dogClass isn't instantiated?

Comment: @Stultuske dogClass is the name I was returning from the trace... Dog inherits a field of type String that is initialized in the constructor. The Dog class is not instantiated because it is not required by the problem, but it can be done without problems. What is your contribution to the discussion?

Comment: my contribution is that your answer makes 0 sense. why would there have to be a dogClass variable? There already is a name variable.

Comment: @Stultuske It's an extra step, I didn't realise, not necessary, but not wrong either. Do you have anything else to complain about to satisfy your ego?

Comment: "it's an extra step", no, it is a screwed up design. dogClass is not related to name, nor should it be treated as if it is

Comment: @Stultuske then what does it refer to? Consider that it's a field I took from the track, I didn't make it up, I thought it was the reference to the name in the parent class. On its own from the name it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: yes, the fact that it 's in the question, while Dog supposedly already extends Animal, shows that it's not "name". It can be "hunting dog", for instance.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my description is not clear enough, the field `dogClass` represents an additional field of the subclass, which makes sense in some scenarios... @Stultuske @Eugenio